# Return response from spring rest controller with query parameters

Tags: java, spring, controller, query-string

I'd like to send 302 response with redirectUri and query parameters. I am able to fill the location but not sure how to include values as query parameters in response of the controller.

I have tried to add values to body but I'd like to send them in query parameters.

```
public ResponseEntity<Void> redirect(@RequestBody MultiValueMap<String,String> formVars, HttpServletResponse response) {
    String clientId = formVars.getFirst(CLIENT_ID);
    String redirectUri = formVars.getFirst(REDIRECT_URI);
    String redirectToken = formVars.getFirst(REDIRECTION_TOKEN);

    ResponseHandler<RedirectDto> redirectDtoResponseHandler = redirectService.redeemRedirectToken(redirectToken);
    if (!redirectDtoResponseHandler.isPresent()) {
        //handle error
    }

    redirectDtoResponseHandler.map(redirectDto -> toCookie(redirectDto.getCustomerSessionId()))
        .ifPresent(response::addCookie);

    URI uri = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl(redirectUri).build().toUri();

    //I'd like to add clientId as query param in this response?
    return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.FOUND).location(uri).build();
}
```

I'd like to add clientId as query param in this response?

Comment: Can't you just return it in the body instead of a Void?

Comment: Nope, it's 302 response
it can't have body. We can return things either in params or headers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UriComponents uriComponents = UriComponentsBuilder.newInstance()
      .scheme("http").host(redirectUri)
      .path("/").query("clientId={keyword}").buildAndExpand(clientId);
```